# Read-Only ADO.NET Connection String for Excel

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net

I'm trying to prevent the following from coming up when reading an Excel file using ADO.NET:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

I know it is happening because another user has the file open, but I can't get rid of it.  I've tried adding `Read Only=True;` to my connection string, but that doesn't work.  I've also tried to set the `Mode` of the connection to read-only, but I can't figure out how to in C#.

Here is my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=test.xls; Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try using a provider other than the Microsoft Jet Database Engine?

Comment: There's tons: http://www.connectionstrings.com/, but not that many that work on files. If you can't get get the jet provider opening the file, why not try opening it the old fashioned way? with `Open` ?

Comment: I am opening a file when my application opens to get some data (and no, I cant store the data in another type of file).  When I open it the old fashioned way, it takes 5 minutes.  This way it takes 10 seconds (if the file isn't already opened by somebody else :)

Comment: I don't mean open the file in excel, that would take an extremely long time, I'm talking about opening the file using:
`Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum: Do While Not EOF(iFileNum): Line Input #iFileNum, Fields`

I've run speed tests against the Jet Provider and in the absolute worst case, this method is only about 3 times slower than the jet engine, so it would take 30 seconds. In the best case, it takes the same amount of time or less, especially when you're reading all columns, not just selecting a subset of columns.

Comment: I'll give it a try - may be a while though.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also come up if you don't have permissions for the file, not just when it's exclusively open. In any event, I always found the best workaround for this problem was to automate a copy of the file to a new temp file. Copies are almost instantaneous, even for large files, so they shouldn't slow you down much, and since your application is only read-only, you don't have to worry about discarding the temp file afterwards.

Furthermore, this will clear up any permissions issues that can be cleared up. If you have read permissions, the copy will work, if not, then there's no workaround anyways. You will have full permissions for the copied file if you make the destination path of the temp copy the same path as the workbook. (`Application.Path`)

Use the `FileCopy srcFile, destName` command for this.

Comment: I do have Full Access to the file. I found that if I manually open the file in excel (and tell it to open in read-only mode) and then try to access it with ado.net, I can connect.  I'd like to open it read only though - there must be a way.

Comment: So I caved and tried this, but my original file is on a network, not a mapped drive. FileCopy doesn't work on non-mapped drives. Is there a way to copy the file still?

Comment: This is getting interesting, I wonder if the drive not being mapped has something to do with the original Jet provider having a problem. Can you manually copy the file to a mapped drive and see if all the same problems occur? This might be one of those little known limitations.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, I will have to copy off the network for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you said you tried changing the mode to read only, how exactly did you do that?

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681754%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), by default, the OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Jet opens Microsoft Jet databases in read/write mode. To open a database in read-only mode, set the Mode property on the [ADO Connection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681546%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to adModeRead.

So in C# it should have looked like:

```
ADODB.Connection myConn = new new ADODB.Connection();
myConn.Mode = adModeRead; //1
myConn.Open(strConectionString, null, null, -1);
```

Comment: If I do this, is there a way to fill a DataSet with the data from the connection?  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you can use `Set recordset = connection.Execute (CommandText, RecordsAffected, Options)` to perform some query using the connection, and you can fill a DataSet from the recordset using the `OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, RecordSet, "TableName")` command or the `OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet.Table, RecordSet)` command

Comment: Sample code here: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/440071-filling-dataset-ado-recordset-record